# Android deeplink not work properly

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, deep-linking, motorola-droid

I have some strange problem here. This works in Samsung s4(I9500) and not in Moto G (XT1040).

Manifest:

```
 <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
     <data android:scheme="XXX" />
 </intent-filter>
 <intent-filter android:label="XXX">
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
     <data android:scheme="XXX" android:host="me" />
 </intent-filter>
```

Link:
android-app://com.mypackage/XXX/me

When I try to enter this link, when I use Moto G it goes to the first filter. 
s4 goes to the expected filter (the second).

In my activity, I have something like this:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent != null) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Uri data = intent.getData();
        checkDeepLinking(action, data);
    }
}
```

I debug this and see that intent.getdata() was "XXX:" not "XXX://me"

Thanks!

Comment: Intent-filters does not have different sdk implementations... =/

Comment: Yes I know but I don't have any idea about whats going on. Do you?

Comment: @DaniG You got the solution ? For me sometimes its happening

Comment: uhm... I really don't remember. Right now, you can use App link assistant in android studio.

Answer (score 0):

Can you test your implementation using the tools that Google provides in their documentation (https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/test) and later publish here the log details and results obtained?

According to the documentation, you should always have present the [android:host] parameter in your manifest, so that could be an issue here. Also, do the two mobile devices have the same versions of Android and Google Search App?

Cheers.